# Should small companies code their sites to support Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cross-browser

I work on small sites for tanning salons and stuff. We don't support ActiveX-specific stuff on IE, and we support Firefox. I've noticed some weird behavior with Chrome. My browser stats say <1% of my visitors use Chrome.

I've heard people say it's nowhere near best in class. But I like the way everything runs in its own process and stuff.

Is Chrome going to get popular enough that I need to code for it? By the time it gets popular, will its weird rendering get fixed?

Comment: I'd expect that webkit and Chrome will both be showing a lot of changes.  It may well come to you, rather than require your fixing it.  Chrome is my primary browser now, but personally I'd rather see everyone support IPv6 first (now that I have it), THEN worry about browser compatibility.  :-)

Comment: Edited the question to make it visible to the world,in four years  where chrome stands now ;)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Write code to standards first, then for different rendering engines if needed. Never design websites for specific browsers, it's a very slippery slope.

Comment: Easier said than done, you still have to view the code in a browser.  So your advice is pie in the sky.  You really can't get any better than using Firefox with Firebug and HTML Validator.  Then cross your fingers and try in other browsers.

Comment: @TravisO - The variance between browsers is significantly less now than it was back in in the IE5/Netscape days. Writing your markup in line with the standards then adding the handful of lines for any significant differences is the reality for many UI coders. Not "pie in the sky."

Comment: I think it's wise to test your sites on IE, Firefox, Safari, Opera, and yes, Chrome. However, I agree with you. Support standards first, then work around the buggy implementations. In my experience, standards-based sites usually only need to be "massaged" for IE, the other browsers play nice.

Comment: Debugging on multiple browsers can help you avoid accidentally relying on quirks in your primary browser. You don‘t have to fix every issue in every browser, but running through different browsers can be a good way to spot issues you didn’t realise you had.

Answer (score 17):

its a good reason to improve support for WebKit browsers in general (do you not have any customers using Safari on a Mac?)

Comment: Yes!  Google Chrome is using WebKit, along with Safari on Mac and Safari on iPhone/iPod Touch.

Answer (score 11):

Chrome is still in early beta and it's rendering is not bug free, I also experience critical UI issues in Chrome.  I do plan on my web apps working in Chrome, but I've made a decision not to change anything until Chrome hits a more mature level.

[Google has recently said they will be bringing Chrome to a non beta state very soon](http://news.cnet.com/8301-17939_109-10120049-2.html) (unlike their past history of leaving things in beta for 5yrs or so).

Also, if you plan on using Chrome to webdev in this beta state, you'll want to [install the "Developer Channel"](http://dev.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel/) which gives you access to a newer versions than the public version, very important at this stage of the browser.  As of 12/10/2008 the dev version of Chrome is 0.4.154.33

Comment: I have chrome crashing on a w3c validated CSS file.

Comment: Just an FYI: Chrome is now out of Beta (Dec 12, 2008)

Answer (score 9):

Chrome uses WebKit, a fairly standard rendering engine. Safari uses it also, and it doesn't sound like WebKit is going away. If you have the necessary resources, I would advise to look into fixing it up.

Answer (score 3):

Jimmy has a very good point there, Chrome and Safari are both based off WebKit. If it fails on Chrome, chances are good it's likely breaking on Safari, Nokia S60 browser and the rest as well.

Answer (score 2):

The key is to write to standards, using semantically correct and well-formed markup.  Make the base implementation work for most browsers (as many as possible) and make adjustments to handle the remaining ones.

Writing sites that are tailored to be "best viewed with" a certain browser perpetuate the browser vendor's inability to strive for standards compliance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing Javascript work and this is resulting in noticeable differences between browsers, then I'd definitely recommend using a third-party framework like jQuery so you can work with a common browser-agnostic interface. If, however, your differences are due to the HTML/CSS on your pages, then I would always prioritise the most popular browsers according to your site's statistics. If <1% are using Chrome then I would seriously consider spending the time on other tasks instead of investigating something that may actually be a problem with a new browser that is still in very early beta.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not yet: Chrome is still changing fairly quickly, and they're targeting being fully compliant with the various standards and tests.   If you try to follow Chrome right now, you'll probably be tracking lots of little flaky changes that you'll eventually want to reverse.

Answer (score 1):

I would test the pages with Chrome. If you've done good job, there shouldn't be that many problems.

Actually it IS possible to write one code that works on all browsers (well, maybe not IE 6 or earlier)  ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my view it all depends on your clients, and their users.
I'd check your weblogs and see if it is a significant percentage.

If it's getting significant, to the point where your clients might be losing money, I'd discuss it with them and see if they're willing to pay extra to bring your sites in line with Chrome.

Personally I wouldn't worry about it till it gets to at least 1% consistently.
And even then I'd still talk to your clients about it first.

On the other hand it's quite possible it'll get 5% market share in the next year or so.
It is Google after all.

Answer (score 1):

As an end user, I get a bit annoyed if some site doesn't support Chrome: basically, I begin to ignore it, but not before writing a complaint first. That said, it's sometimes probably Chrome's fault, not the designers. However, I don't really care whose fault it is, since all I want is the page rendered properly and functioning as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware of several large companies that have outlawed use of Chrome until it allows installation on other than the C drive.  I would guess that if Chrome overcomes this and some of the UI issues mentioned elsewhere, it will become very popular.  I think you should plan to support Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Both the larger web businesses and smaller web businesses that I personally work with do nothing with Chrome.  It isn't on their browser radar.  And some of the larger ones are big ecommerce.

Therefore, I do not devote coding time towards supporting Chrome.  I do run it for research and market development purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I never code to support beta products. Wait for them to finish making their software before you start changing yours to support it.

Answer (score 1):

You should target browsers based on what your *customers are using*.  If 80% of your customers are using IE, then it would be prudent to test your site primarily on IE.  If you know your customers are using FF, then it would be prudent to test your site primarily on FF.

That said, Google Chrome's market share is basically a rounding error, so no--I wouldn't bother.  Unless, of course, you know ahead of time that a significant number of your users are using it.

(e.g. for an iphone app I wrote, we found that a majority of our users were browsing to our site *from an iphone*--I know, absolutely amazing, earth shattering concept.  Thus, we started doing the majority of our web site testing against the iphone browser)

Answer (score 1):

First target the current standard, then prioritize by how much ruckus your users make (if you have a very vocal 1% is still a very vocal 1% of your userbase)

Answer (score 1):

Even if Chrome is out of beta, for me is still in beta. Because Chrome can't display well png24 with opacity change (i tried to do a fadeIn/fadeOut with jquery on a png image and i get an ANNOYING white flash before image animation; you can see the problem [here](http://claudiunenu.ro))

Comment: For what it's worth, that link doesn't have any white flashes in Chrome 3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should need to code anything specific for Chrome.  If they say that web standards are important to them, then Chrome will eventually follow those standards to a tee.

I also don't believe Chrome will get very popular.  When I saw it the first thing I thought was "Wow...  Mozilla with a G print on it."  And I have not really been very impressed since.

Bottom line:  You should make an attempt to make your site support the major browsers.  Opera, IE, Firefox.  Usually, following web standards and best practices will accomplish this.  Other times you need to create work arounds or force browsers to act a certain way.  I.E.  Firefox and IE use a different border model.  You can force at least FF to use the same border model as IE does.

Comment: that should be "tee" or "T", not "tea"